# How can I change my .htaccess file in cakephp

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I have URL like :

localhost/admin/app/webroot

For this the css in default.ctp taken /app/webroot/css/style.css path.
so  my css is not loading.

Should I have to change .htaccess file for this ?
There are 3 .htaccess file in project.

1) which is located in admin/.htaccess

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]

RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]

2) which is located in admin/app/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]

RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
```

3) which is located in admin/app/webroot/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

please help to resolve my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you have written on your default.ctp

Comment: echo $this->Html->css('style');

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of dealing with this is to set your application up in "Production Mode" as described [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/deployment.html#set-document-root)

Essentially it means you point your document root to the /app/webroot directory of your Cake App, this makes everything really simple and means you can use the default .htaccess files to handle the rewriting.

If you are trying to put this into a subdirectory you might need to set the base for Rewrite to work on:

```
RewriteBase /admin
```

This also assumes you have mod_rewrite enabled on your server!

Comment: on which .htaccess file I have to put this code out of 3 ? and Yes mod_rewrite is enabled

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /admin
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: I'm pretty sure its only the app/webroot/.htaccess that is needed if you set it up with app/webroot to be be the document root for apache. That is the only one that I have ever used.

Comment: Yes , I have put it on the same, but  its not working for me . :(

Comment: Just FYI : I am using the Xampp server in ubuntu

Comment: Why are you using Xampp on ubuntu? Just set up a normal lamp stack with the following:

`sudo apt-get install tasksel && sudo tasksel install lamp-server`

Comment: Yes, but Right now I have to use Xampp in ubuntu, but Is there any issue of xampp or lamp ?

Comment: There is no need to use Xampp on linux, the instructions I have provided above should work for any system but Xampp has too many other variables that can cause issues, you are better off just using a standard lamp server when developing on linux.

Comment: I have added the code but its not working

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /admin
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>

Comment: I have check this code in Mac machine also, but its not working for me

Comment: I found the answer :

If we can add 

Configure::write('App.base', '/admin/');

in bootstrap.php file then it works for me.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer :

If we can add

Configure::write('App.base', '/admin/');

in bootstrap.php file then it works for me.

Thanks for your help.